# How can I fix the error in the code written in asm language?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, nasm, bubble-sort

```
nasm test.asm -f elf64
ld test.o
./a.out
Segmentation Fault
```

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rbp,rsp     ;save stack pointer
    sub rsp,8000        ;reserve 1000 times 64bit value


    mov rbx,rbp     ;save base pointer into rbx for Effective Address
    mov cx,1001     ;equal to for(int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
load:
    sub cx,1
    jz .exit

    rdrand eax      ;get random 64bit value in eax
    sub rbx,8
    mov [rbx],eax       ;save the random value in stack

    jmp load
.exit:
    mov rbx,rbp
    mov cx,1000     ;equal to for(int i=0; i<999; ++i)

sort:               ;Bubble Sort start here
    sub cx,1
    jz .exit

    sub rbx,8
    mov rax,[rbx]       ;last value in  rax
    mov rcx,[rbx-8]     ;last-1 value in rcx
    cmp rax,rcx
    jge .noOperation    ;if rax >= rcx continue

    mov [rbx],rcx       ;change
    mov [rbx-8],rax     ;change
.noOperation:
    jmp sort
.exit:
    mov rbx,rbp
    mov cx,1001     ;equal to for(int i=0; i<1000; ++i)


print:              ;classic decimal print
.init:
    sub cx,1
    jz .exit

    sub rbx,8
    mov rax,[rbx]
.divinit:
    mov rsi,10
    mov rdi,1
    sub rsp,1
    mov [rsp],byte 10
.div:
    mov rdx,0
    div rsi
    add dl,48
    add rdi,1
    sub rsp,1
    mov [rsp],byte dl
    cmp rax,0
    jnz .div
.syscall:
    mov rax,1
    mov rdx,rdi
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,rsp
    syscall

    add rsp,rdx
    jmp .init

.exit:
    add rsp,8000


programexit:

    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
```

I decided to make bubble sort algorithm in assembly language (NASM - Linux). The program sorts 1000 8byte values from smallest to largest and prints them. But I am getting Segmentation Error. Where is the mistake?
..........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What debugging have you done?

Comment: @Nic3500 I didn't. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> `rdrand eax      ;get random 64bit value in eax`

That gets you a 32-bit value. You probably want `rdrand rax`.

The crash is here:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
sort () at test.asm:30
30          mov rcx,[rbx-8]     ;last-1 value in rcx

(gdb) p/x $rbx
$1 = 0x7fffff7ff000
```

The problem is that in your `sort` you've set things up for `cx` to be the loop counter, but then blow it up by loading `rcx` with something else.

You *do* realize that `cx`, `ecx` and `rcx` are all the same physical register, right?

P.S. Your bubble sort can't be correct because it has an algorithmic complexity of `O(N)`, but we know that it's impossible to sort anything in linear time. Bubble sort needs two nested loops, and you've only got one.